# Accepting string from user in an array of pointers in C us

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, c-strings

The code tries to get names of 3 students and their marks in 3 subjects and print total score as well as average of score of each student along with their names.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *names[3];
    int test1[3],test2[3],test3[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&(*(names+i)));
        scanf("%d",&test1[i]);
        scanf("%d",&test2[i]);
        scanf("%d",&test3[i]);
    }
    int j=0;
    while(j<3){
        
        printf("%s",*(names+j));
        printf(" %d ",test1[j]+test2[j]+test3[j]);
        printf("%.f\n",(test1[j]+test2[j]+test3[j])/3.0);
        j++;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run this code, I am not getting output of any of the printf's written in while loop . Can anyone help me please?

Comment: A general advice: don't access array elements like `*(names+j)` but use the notation `names[j]` it's much more readable and maintainable

Comment: Welcome to SO. You only have an array with 3 pointers to characters. You do not initialized that array with pointers to valid memory. You cannot read strings into invalid memory addresses

Comment: Vivek, `"%s"` will not save a name with a space in it.  Might the names contain spaces?

Answer (score 4):

The variable `names` is an array of pointers. But you never make these pointers actually point anywhere. Any attempt to dereference them will lead to *undefined behavior*.

***Also*** the type of `&names[i]` (which is what `&(*(names+i))` really is) is `char **`, which is *not* what the `scanf` format `%s` expects. Mismatching format specifier and argument type *also* leads to undefined behavior.

What you should use is an array of *arrays* of characters:

```
char names[3][256];
```

and let the sub-arrays decays to pointers to their first element (the expression `names[i]` decays to `&names[i][0]` which have the type `char *`):

```
scanf("%255s", names[i]);
```

Note that I added a length specifier to avoid writing out of bounds of `names[i]`.

Then print as a normal string:

```
printf("%s %d %f\n", names[j],
       test1[j] + test2[j] + test3[j],
       (test1[j] + test2[j] + test3[j]) / 3.0);
```

Comment: So can this problem be solved using array of pointers? If yes, then please tell me how.

Comment: @VivekPatel Why do you need pointer? What problem is that supposed to solve? And yes it's possible to solve using pointers, but I just don't see the point (pun not intended).

Comment: You can only use a pointer if it points to something. Do you know of a way to allocate memory for the pointer?

Comment: yeah, I caught the mistake. I declared character arrays stud1[256], stud2[256], stud3[256] and added them in *names[3] ={stud1 , stud2 , stud3 }, so now names point to base addresses of stud1,stud2 and stud3.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you included too many headers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

Actually only declarations from the header `<stdio.h>` are used in the program. So remove all other headers and leave only the header `<stdio.h>`

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

In this declaration

```
char *names[3];
```

there is declare an uninitialized array of pointers that have indeterminate values.

So this call of scanf

```
scanf("%s",&(*(names+i)));
```

that should be written at least like

```
scanf("%s",*(names+i));
```

because the expression `&(*(names+i))` has the type `char **` but the function expects an argument of the type `char *` invokes undefined behavior.

To store strings you need to declare an array of character arrays as for example

```
char names[3][100];
```

But in any case your approach with declaring four arrays looks is not good.

It will be better to declare a structure as for example

```
enum { NumberOfStudents = 3, NumberOfMarks = 3, MaxNameLen = 100 };

struct Student
{
    char name[MaxNameLen];
    unsigned int marks[NumberOfMarks];
};
```

In this case you could declare only one array of three object of the type `struct Student`.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { NumberOfStudents = 3, NumberOfMarks = 3, MaxNameLen = 100 };

    struct Student
    {
        char name[MaxNameLen];
        unsigned int marks[NumberOfMarks];
    };

    struct Student students[NumberOfStudents];

    printf( "Enter information about %d srudents.\n", NumberOfStudents );

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStudents; i++)
    {
        printf( "Name of student #%d: ", i + 1 );

        scanf( "%99s", students[i].name );

        printf( "Enter his %d marks: ", NumberOfMarks );

        for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfMarks; j++)
        {
            scanf( "%u", &students[i].marks[j] );
        }
    }

    puts( "\nHere are the students with their total and average marks." );

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStudents; i++)
    {
        printf( "%s: ", students[i].name );

        unsigned total = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfMarks; j++)
        {
            total += students[i].marks[j];
        }

        printf( "%u %.1f\n", total, ( double )total / NumberOfMarks );
    }

}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter information about 3 srudents.
Name of student #1: Tom
Enter his 3 marks: 4 5 3
Name of student #2: Mary
Enter his 3 marks: 5 5 4
Name of student #3: Bob
Enter his 3 marks: 6 6 4

Here are the students with their total and average marks.
Tom: 12 4.0
Mary: 14 4.7
Bob: 16 5.3
```